# Xamarin Studio OSX and Windows Builds

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a beginner question regarding Xamarin Studio. I wrote a prototype app in Windows Form using Visual Studio and I now want to flesh it out and deploy to both Windows desktop and OSX. Someone suggested using Xamarin Studio but I have run into an issue. When I try to build on a Mac for OSX all I get is a .exe. I am  new to OSX development and am having trouble figuring out how to continue. Is there a build configuration I am missing? There doesn't seem to be any options for build targets.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

the .exe can be run with Mono, but what you may be looking for is in the "Build" menu (at least, in the latest Beta), then "Archive for publishing" then "Sign and Distribute"